# How can I farm most effectively for portal keys in a short timespan

Tags: ingress

When planning Ops that require many keys for a particular portal, I find farming these keys can take a very long time, for example:

- capture the portal
- drop any existing keys for that portal (or pop them into a capsule)
- hack the portal
- wait 5 minutes for cool down
- do steps 2-4 again until burn out

Which will get me 4 keys in 20 minutes.

Obviously I can add a heat sink to speed up the cool down, but what is the most efficient way to farm as many keys as possible in a short time (say 30 minutes or so)?

Comment: Please see my post which is very similar to this one: 

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202201/what-is-the-best-method-for-a-single-user-to-key-farm-a-portal

Comment: For a big op, the best bet is simply not to do it alone. Working together you benefit from one another's mods, get better loot while you're at it, and the time will pass a lot quicker having someone to chat with. Bring a stopwatch and a deck of cards or a ball and it will be over before you know it started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not much you can to, other than deploying Heat Sink and Multi-hack mods.

If time is the limit, the most efficient would be:

- Hack 1 time
- Deploy Very Rare Heat Sink: Will set cool down time to 90 seconds
- Deploy Very Rare Multi-hack: Will give you 16 hacks before burnout
- Hack 16 times

Makes 17 hacks in ~24 minutes.

If you have a buddy, let him deploy the same mods you did. That will give you 22 hacks with a cool down time of 58 seconds, so potentially 22 keys in 22 minutes. For each of you.

If you have more time, obviously you should wait with deploying the Heat Sinks to max out the hacks before resetting.

If you don't want to waste the very rare mods, do not need 22 keys or have more time to wait, use only the rare & commons. [Here](http://kennyboy.org/ingress/) is a very nice tool to calculate the cool down times and max hacks with any combination of deployed mods.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the things mentioned by others, there's a new hero in town :

> MUFG capsule

This capsule basically replicates a "few" items present in it after a "specific" duration regularly.

The reason I have quoted the words above is because, MUFG doesn't have a fixed set of operational rules.

My personal experience was that MUFG replicates the items over a period of 15- 24 hours.

Items which are more in number will be replicated most frequently.

For example, I have included 60 L8 Xmps & 14 Keys, then after 24 hours Xmps started increasing till a week and the finally my key replicated.

So if you already have a good amount of keys, then MUFG can prove to be helpful.